# How can I fix adb in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

```
[2015-02-13 00:03:06 - hhh] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2015-02-13 00:03:06 - hhh] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2015-02-13 00:03:06 - hhh] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'F:\android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Although location is right

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035456/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occurred & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a check list I used to do when I had problems like this. Nowadays, I use Android Studio and find I run into these kinds of issues far less often.

- Restart Eclipse and see if the problem persists
- If you're on Windows, open the task manager and end the adb process. Restart Eclipse. (If you're on macOSX, I do not know how to end a process. You'll have to Google it. Sorry!)
- Once again, make 100% sure the android SDK path in your eclipse settings is correct. If you make a change, restart Eclipse.

EDIT: Follow the links provided by Josef in the comment he/she responded to you with.

Comment: i did kill adb and start it >>>and Restart  same result

Comment: Try doing a clean build to get your R java file back

Comment: not work . i tired from that error ..same sdk ,jdk and Eclipse in my friend lap work there and me not

Comment: Try looking up the error you're getting on Google. I've found these possible solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260118/failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080423/failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version-the-connection-to-adb-is-down-a

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

Close the Eclipse if running
Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
type adb kill-server (Eclipse should be closed before issuing these commands)
then type adb start-server
No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.
Now you can start Eclipse again.
it worked for me this way.

Restart your phone as well!
[[reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured)